# What is the opposite of "your pee is dark" in everyday conversation, for example, "your pee is clear"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I often say this to my children:

**If you drink little water, your pee is dark** (1)

And they reply:

**If you drink much water, your pee is light** (2)

Because they know the opposite pair "**dark-light**"

But I think (2) is not correct, it should be "**clear**" or "**transparent**"

For example,

**If you drink much water, your pee is clear** (3) ("**transparent**" is too technical)

**Which one are correct: (1), (2), or (3) in everyday casual conversations?**

Comment: This is not an argument that one normally talks about with friends. Urine should never be transparent, if it is there's something wrong. Pale yellow urine, sounds all right to me. Check it out on the WebMD site.

Comment: [*If everything is normal and healthy, **the color should be a pale yellow to gold**. That hue comes from a pigment your body makes called urochrome.*](https://www.webmd.com/urinary-incontinence-oab/truth-about-urine#:~:text=yours%20turns%20out.-,What%20Color%20Is%20Your%20Pee%3F,light%20or%20dark%2C%20also%20changes.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, "**if you drink much water, your pee is pale yellow**"? "**pale yellow**" is too technical, what do we call it in everyday conversation?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, maybe "**if you drink much water, your pee is pale**" sounds better

Comment: "Much" is commonly used in interrogatives: "*How much water do you drink?*" and in negative sentences "*There isn't much water left.*" In affirmative sentences, I think "a lot of" and "too much"" sound better "*I drink **a lot of water** but  **drinking too much** is bad for you*"

Comment: I wouldn't call 'pale yellow' technical! Don't you talk about colours in everyday conversation?

Comment: @KateBunting, "**pale yellow**" might not be very exact, because especially if a child drinks a lot of water, the urine looks almost like tap water which is not yellow.

Comment: In that case, it's colourless.

Comment: I think "clear" is a good term.  "Colourless" works too.  Also, we should be cautious about making medical pronouncements on ELL; to say that it should "never" be transparent is questionable: "If a person has clear urine occasionally, it is most likely that they are very well hydrated on those days. However, a person may wish to speak to a doctor if they have consistently clear urine" ( https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/326740#hydration ). Clear urine comes in the "healthy pee" spectrum in the graphic shown here: https://www.nhsinform.scot/campaigns/hydration

Comment: Fyi, we **say**: drink a lot of water. No one who speaks good English goes around saying: If you drink much water in everyday speech. The light/dark thing does not work very well at all.

Answer (score 2):

'Light' is certainly the first word that comes to mind for me (that was the word your title question made me think of before even reading the actual post). Conversational language is much looser than written, so long as all parties understand the meaning you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

"Light yellow" and "pale yellow", or "light" and "pale", work for urine that is a light shade of yellow, but if you are referring to urine that is the same colour as tap water, "clear" or "colourless" is correct.

> If your urine is clear, then it can signal that you're healthy. Typically, the lighter your urine, the healthier you are. But as the 'ideal' healthy urine colour is straw yellow, clear wee might not be such a good thing. While you could just have a very well-hydrated body, it could also mean that you are over-hydrated or could even be a sign of diabetes. ([Daily Mirror](https://www.mirror.co.uk/lifestyle/health/what-colour-your-urine-really-7379582))